# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: django

Here is the error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
The included URLconf '<module 'basicsiteApp' from '/Users/msa/trydjango/basicsite/basicsiteApp/__init__.py'>' 
does not appear to have any patterns in it. 
If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably 
caused by a circular import.
```

I don't have anything written in `init.py` because I don't know what I need to write in it so it can work.

Below is what I have in `views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import  SignUpForm
from django.contrib import messages

def signup(request):
  if request.method == 'POST'
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      messages.success(request, 'Account Created')
      return render(request, 'signup.html')
    else:
      form = SignUpForm()
    render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Basicsite/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('basicsiteApp')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

basicsiteApp/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'basicsiteApp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.signup, name='signup')
]
```

Comment: Do you have urls.py in your app?

Comment: Update your question with `Full TraceBack`.

Comment: yes I have urls.py

Answer (score 1):

I know it comes late, but if someone (like me) faces the same problem:

In your "Basicsite/urls.py"

> path('', include('basicsiteApp')),

it should be

> path('', include('basicsiteApp.urls')),

implying django to use the **basicsiteApp/urls.py** file instead of **basicsiteApp/*init*.py**